# linq2db integration with Entity Framework Core and dbContext.GetCte missing

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq2db

linq2db has possibility to "integrate" with EF Core context:

[EF Core integration](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

> In your code you need to initialize integration using following call:
> LinqToDBForEFTools.Initialize();

but after only that line there is no method `GetCte` in EF Core context.

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.; Database=dbName;User Id=sa; Password=ble; encrypt=false", options => options.CommandTimeout(10))
                    .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Query.Name, DbLoggerCategory.Database.Connection.Name, DbLoggerCategory.Database.Name }
                    );
                    // .UseQueryTrackingBehavior( QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
        
    LinqToDBForEFTools.Initialize();
}
```

USING

```cs
using (var _dbContext = new CompanyContext())
{
    _dbContext.GetCte - not found
    _dbContext.BulkCopy - found
}
```

Is it possible to use `GetCte` with EF Core `DbContext` or linq2db  full configuration should be done to have a possibility to use recursive CTE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to work

```cs
using (var _dbContext = new CompanyContext())
{
    using (var db = _dbContext.CreateLinqToDBConnection())
    {

    }
}
```